# Avoid if-else or switch-case statements for deciding

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm developing a generic search form, that search controls in that form are depends on type of `<T>`properties, for example if T is `Order`,

```
public class Order
{
   public string OrderNumber {get; set;} // search control is 1 TextBox
   public decimal OrderWeight {get; set;} // search controls are 2 TextBox (for accepting a range)
}
```

the search form will be something like this

[image]

i used this statements in my form for deciding that what are appropriate controls for each `T` property:

```
if (propertyType.Name == "System.String")
   InsertOneTextBox(paramInfo);
else 
   if(propertyType.Name == "System.Int32" || propertyType.Name == "System.Decimal") 
      InsertTwoTextBoxs(paramInfo);
   else
    if(propertyType.Name == "System.DateTime") 
      InsertTwoDateTimePickers(paramInfo);
    else
       if(propertyType.Name == someotherconditions)    
          InsertOneComboBox(paramInfo);
   ....
```

is there any best practice for avoid using `if` `else`s or `switch` `case` for deciding that what are appropriate controls set for each property type?

Comment: Could you place braces in the `if-else` example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build some kind of map:

**Upd**.

According to your comment:

```
    // somewhere this class is defined in your code
    class ParamInfo {}

    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<ParamInfo>> typeToControlsInsertActionMap;

    public MyForm()
    {
        typeToControlsInsertActionMap = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ParamInfo>>
        {
            { typeof(string), InsertOneTextBox },
            { typeof(int), InsertTwoTextBoxs },
            { typeof(decimal), InsertTwoTextBoxs },

            // etc.
        };
    }

    private void InsertOneTextBox(ParamInfo paramInfo) {}
    private void InsertTwoTextBoxs(ParamInfo paramInfo) {}
```

Here `Action<ParamInfo>` is a delegate, which inserts appropriate controls, depending on property type:

```
var paramInfo = // ...
var propertyType = // ...    

typeToControlsInsertActionMap[propertyType](paramInfo);
```

Note, that you shouldn't check type name in your case. Use [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class using TinyType and make your input string strong typed. Based on these inputs create 4 strategies ( Talking about Strategy Pattern) all driving from same interface. Create a Factory class and inject in your class where you need these strategies. Now inject this factory in your class let your stringtyped input and factory decide what kind of insertion you want to do ( one text box/ 2 text box etc.)